# display random numbers in a modal popup

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to generate random number and display it on a pop up modal on a button click event. However it does not seem to function properly.
I am using bootstrap and javascript.

When I click on the button open modal I would like the random numbers to be displayed in the textbox inside the modal.

The error says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'randomfield' of undefined

Any help is appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" onClick="randomString(this);" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Please make a note of your ticket</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" id="randomfield" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
  <script>
function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 8;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `getElementById` to set the random string in the model textbox having id value as `randomfield`:

```js
function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 8;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.getElementById('randomfield').value = randomstring;
    //or even this as you are using JQuery
    //$('#randomfield').val(randomstring);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" onClick="randomString(this);" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Please make a note of your ticket</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" id="randomfield" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Or use this: `$('#randomfield').val(randomstring);` as jQuery is linked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <script>
     function randomString() {
       var chars = 
          "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            var string_length = 8;
              var randomstring = '';
          for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
          var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
             randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
          }

                 return randomstring;

          }
       var box = document.querySelector('#randomfield');
       var element = addEventListener('click',function(){
      box.value = randomString();
               })

     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This code is Runable Try it     
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" onClick="randomString(this);" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Please make a note of your ticket</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="text" id="randomfield" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
  <script>
function randomString() {
    var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var string_length = 8;
    var randomstring = '';
    for (var i=0; i<string_length; i++) {
        var rnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
        randomstring += chars.substring(rnum,rnum+1);
    }
    document.getElementById("randomfield").value = randomstring;

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I gave your code a little try.

To make it work you have to adjust 2 little things:

1 ) add closing `</script>` tag add the end of the document

2) change `document.randform.randomfield.value = randomstring;`

to `document.getElementById('randomfield').value = randomstring;`

### Explanation

For getting access to elements in the DOM you should use `document.getElementById()` or a similar function. Javascript's `Document` Object provides an interface for manipulating your html page(DOM), it does not represent all your html directly.

Please consider reading the docs about javascript's `Document` Object and about the `getElementById()` function.

=>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document

=> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById